# How to sum a value from the prev column to create a new value for the next column

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: CLICK THE IMAGE PLEASE][Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOpdB.png)

Please see the image above to show you an example of what I am trying to do. Thanks all.

I have a sales column with sales figures, I want to create a new forecast column and start it where the sales column has ended in this case 472031 + 34546. See the example

**Sales Column**

```
34546
56497
89245
122952
160134
187809
227312
264421
308869
342777
388785
430483
472031
```

the latest sales figure was 472031 by adding 34546 then the below column will be 506,576 and so on.

See below for examples. Thanks in advance.

**Sales Forecast Column**

```
506,576 
541,122 
575,668 
610,213 
644,759 
679,305 
713,850 
748,396 
782,942 
817,487 
852,033 
886,579 
921,124 
955,670 
990,216 
1,024,761 
1,059,307 
1,093,853 
1,128,398 
1,162,944 
1,197,490 
1,232,035
```

Comment: Your question and data are unclear to me.  Can you update your question and show the input and output column in a single table along with an explanation of the math?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen  - Sorry my question may not be clear. I have a column with figures called sales column, The sales column shows July 2017 sales with the figure of 472031. I want to forecast for aug, sept, etc by adding july figure to 34546 and that will be aug forecast which is  506,576 and then aug forecast of 506,576 plus 34546 for sept forecast which will be 541,122. I hope you get the idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: So you are just trying to create new column for the forecast that is the current months sales + 34546. The current months sales being the last entry to the sales column?

Comment: @Afrah, copy that comment and paste it into the question instead!

Answer (score 2):

### Create Script

```
    create table sales(
  id int, 
  sales int);

insert into sales(id, sales) values (1,34546);
insert into sales(id, sales) values (2,56497);
insert into sales(id, sales) values (3,89245);
insert into sales(id, sales) values (4,122952);
insert into sales(id, sales) values (5,160134);
insert into sales(id, sales) values (6,187809);
insert into sales(id, sales) values (7,227312);
insert into sales(id, sales) values (8,264421);
insert into sales(id, sales) values (9,308869);
insert into sales(id, sales) values (10,342777);
insert into sales(id, sales) values (11,388785);
insert into sales(id, sales) values (12,430483);
insert into sales(id, sales) values (13,472031);
```

### Queries

**Example 1**

```
select sales.sales, (id *34546)+472031 from sales;
```

**Example2**

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id),
    (((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)) - 1)  * 34546) as extraSales
  FROM sales
)
SELECT
  472031 + cur.extraSales
FROM CTE cur
INNER JOIN CTE prev on prev.rownum = cur.rownum - 1
```

### SQL Fiddles

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4bca1/9

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4bca1/30

Answer (score -1):

To calculate the new sales, you can do

```
select s.*,
       (case when sales = 0
             then row_number() over (partition by sales order by period) * 34546
        end) as inc_sales
from sales s;
```

Then, you want to add in the sales on the date just before.  It so happens that if sales are increasing then this is the maximum of the sales.  The result is:

```
select s.*,
       ((case when sales = 0
              then row_number() over (partition by sales order by period) * 34546
         end) +
        max(sales) over ()
       ) as forecast
from sales s;
```